# Strange MySql error <Can't read from messagefile ...errmsg.sys>

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run MySQL without installation.

I downloaded ≪mysql-5.7.20-macos10.12-x86_64.tar.gz≫. In the extracted folder, I created a file ≪errmsg.sys≫ and set the permissions:

[image]

Then I do:

```
/Users/an/Downloads/mysql-5.7.20-macos10.12-x86_64/bin/mysqld --initialize  --datadir=/Users/an/Downloads/mysql-5.7.20-macos10.12-x86_64/dddd --lc_messages_dir=/Users/an/Downloads/mysql-5.7.20-macos10.12-x86_64
```

which outputs:

```
2017-11-02T15:47:26.271211Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-11-02T15:47:26.272268Z 0 [Warning] Using pre 5.5 semantics to load error messages from /Users/an/Downloads/mysql-5.7.20-macos10.12-x86_64/.
2017-11-02T15:47:26.272275Z 0 [Warning] If this is not intended, refer to the documentation for valid usage of --lc-messages-dir and --language parameters.
2017-11-02T15:47:26.272290Z 0 [ERROR] Can't read from messagefile '/Users/an/Downloads/mysql-5.7.20-macos10.12-x86_64/errmsg.sys'
2017-11-02T15:47:26.273697Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Users/an/Downloads/mysql-5.7.20-macos10.12-x86_64/dddd/ is case insensitive
2017-11-02T15:47:26.453991Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2017-11-02T15:47:26.472988Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2017-11-02T15:47:26.528355Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 2[redacted]3.
2017-11-02T15:47:26.535568Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2017-11-02T15:47:26.536976Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: [redacted]
```

What's the deal with ≪[ERROR] Can't read from messagefile '...errmsg.sys'≫?